# How to import tables of a database in SQL Server to another SQL Server on a different computer programmatically?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, import, export

Good day :-), I'm a beginner when it comes to asking questions here so please bear with me..

First, let me state the example problem at hand:
Company "A" has 4 branches, each placed in different provinces. Each branch, including the main company has an application that inputs a person's profile and saves it to SQL Server database. All data entered by the branching companies must be submitted to the main branch once in a month. But the main director doesn't want those data to be submitted via cloud, he wants it in a flash drive and one individual from each of those branches must travel to the main company, and submit the flash drive with the data inside.

Because if I just use backup & restore method, they will overwrite everything.

Thus, I have created a dummy database to hold those data. Same table, and each table column has the same data type as the original.

Using VB.NET how does one export the table of a database to a dummy database programmatically?

And once exported, how does one import it to the main company's database?

I'll be grateful if you provide me solutions or if you can point me out to the right direction. Also is my method correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can import/export data from one server to another by using Linked Server. 
we can do this also by using sql scripts for using simple select & insert query referring the "Servername.Database.tableName"

Now, if you need to do this in a timely manner, for example for every night you need to import/export the data, what i would suggest is to use Sql Agent. Here you can provide timing to execute the script such as date time and whether it is recursive etc...
with the script of import /export to targeted to specific server.

Ps:
Other approch would be to you use SSIS.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Satish

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestions and see what happens :-) I hope it is the answer to my problem.

Comment: Please mark this as answer, if this works for you. -:)

Comment: just curious,  what approach you considered ?